# If a quartic equation has solutions in the rationals, can the quartic plus a rational constant also have solutions in the rationals?

Tags: functions, rational-numbers

Examples would be appreciated or methods to find such equations and constants.

Edit: The equation is assume to have 4 rational solutions, not necessarily distinct.

Comment: Is the quartic assumed to have only rational solutions, or just at least one? Do we assume four *distinct* solutions?

Comment: coffeemath, it has been edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ x^4 - 65 x^2 + 64 $$
$$ x^4 - 65 x^2 + 784 $$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

$$ x^4 - 1105 x^2 + 17424  $$
$$ x^4 - 1105 x^2 + 82944  $$
$$ x^4 - 1105 x^2 + 138384  $$
$$ x^4 - 1105 x^2 + 304704  $$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

$$ x^4 - 32045  x^2 +  128164 $$
$$ x^4 - 32045  x^2 +  11437924 $$
$$ x^4 - 32045  x^2 +  63329764 $$
$$ x^4 - 32045  x^2 +  123698884 $$
$$ x^4 - 32045  x^2 +  145491844 $$
$$ x^4 - 32045  x^2 +  182304004 $$
$$ x^4 - 32045  x^2 +  239568484 $$
$$ x^4 - 32045  x^2 +  255424324  $$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Comment: How did you go about finding this?

Comment: @JoshuaFarrell where, exactly, did you get the problem?

Comment: An answer to another question I asked https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2681054/are-there-solutions-to-the-following-simultaneous-equations/2681081?noredirect=1#comment5537180_2681081

Comment: @JoshuaFarrell  I realized that i rather liked $(x^2−1)(x^2−4)=x^4−5x^2+4,$ but it did not have enough flexibility because there is essentially just one way to write 5 as the sum of two squares. The product of distinct primes, all $p_i \equiv1 \pmod 4,$ gives a number with several expressions as the sum of two squares, in particular nonzero squares.